# AppCompat ActionBar not appearing on Honeycomb

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to use AppCompat actionBar on honeycomb, but I couldn't manage to do it. It works on API >= 14 though.

Here is my `AppTheme`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>

    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/RobotoTextViewStyle</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/RobotoButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
</style>
```

Other strange thing is that `getActionBar()` always returns `null`.

I saw the same problem on Gingerbread, but not on Honeycomb.

Here is my target APIs:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Whole manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.estudiotrilha.inevent"
    android:versionCode="17"
    android:versionName="2.0.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
                android:name="com.estudiotrilha.inevent.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.estudiotrilha.inevent.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" /> -->

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="InEvent" >

        <meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="in_event.db" />
        <meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="2" />
        <meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME" android:value="com.estudiotrilha.inevent.content" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/fb_id" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="SOME**KEY"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.estudiotrilha.inevent.ProfileEventActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.estudiotrilha.inevent.DemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Transparent"
            android:parentActivityName="com.estudiotrilha.inevent.ProfileEventActivity">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.estudiotrilha.inevent.EventActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.estudiotrilha.inevent.LectureNewActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName="com.estudiotrilha.inevent.EventActivity"  >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.estudiotrilha.inevent.LectureActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName="com.estudiotrilha.inevent.EventActivity"  >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.estudiotrilha.inevent.QuestionarieActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName="com.estudiotrilha.inevent.LectureActivity"  >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.estudiotrilha.inevent.MaterialsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName="com.estudiotrilha.inevent.LectureActivity"  >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.estudiotrilha.inevent.PresenceActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName="com.estudiotrilha.inevent.LectureActivity"  >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.estudiotrilha.inevent.PersonActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName="com.estudiotrilha.inevent.EventActivity"  >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.estudiotrilha.inevent.ProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:parentActivityName="com.estudiotrilha.inevent.ProfileEventActivity" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.estudiotrilha.inevent.SignInActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.estudiotrilha.inevent.SignInWithLinkedInActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:parentActivityName="com.estudiotrilha.inevent.SignInActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                   <data android:scheme="x-oauthflow-linkedin" android:host="com.estudiotrilha.inevent" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.estudiotrilha.inevent.SignInManuallyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName="com.estudiotrilha.inevent.SignInActivity" >
        </activity>
        <!-- <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.estudiotrilha.inevent" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.estudiotrilha.inevent.helper.Broadcast" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.estudiotrilha.inevent.PUSH_NOTIFICATION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>-->
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The main activity:

```
package com.estudiotrilha.inevent;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;

import com.estudiotrilha.inevent.content.ContentHelper;
import com.estudiotrilha.inevent.content.GlobalContents;
import com.estudiotrilha.inevent.content.Person;
import com.estudiotrilha.inevent.fragment.SignInFragment;
import com.estudiotrilha.inevent.helper.ToastHelper;
import com.estudiotrilha.inevent.net.DefAPI;
import com.estudiotrilha.inevent.net.Delegate;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.LinkedInApiClientFactory;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInAccessToken;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthService;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInRequestToken;
import com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook;

public class SignInActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    protected static final String TAG = "SignIn";
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "com.estudiotrilha.inevent";

    public Fragment currentFragment = null;
    public SimpleFacebook mSimpleFacebook = null;

    public LinkedInOAuthService oAuthService;
    public LinkedInApiClientFactory factory;
    public LinkedInRequestToken liToken;

    public ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_with_fragment);

        GlobalContents.setNowActivity(this);

        getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.SignIn);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            currentFragment = new SignInFragment();

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, currentFragment).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mSimpleFacebook.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);

        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "",
                                    getString(R.string.signInProgress), true);

        String verifier = intent.getData().getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");

        class LinkedInToken extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
        {
            String verifier;
            LinkedInAccessToken accessToken;

            public LinkedInToken(String verifier) { this.verifier = verifier; }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params)
            {
                accessToken = oAuthService.getOAuthAccessToken(liToken, verifier); 

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                Log.d("TOKEN", accessToken.getTokenSecret());

                class SignInWithLinkedIn implements Delegate
                {
                    private DefAPI api;

                    public SignInWithLinkedIn()
                    {
                        api = new DefAPI(this);
                        Person.signInWithLinkedIn(accessToken.getTokenSecret(), api);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void requestResults(HttpResponse response, JSONObject result,
                            String value)
                    {
                        dialog.dismiss();

                        if(response != null)
                        {
                            switch(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode())
                            {
                            case 200:
                                ContentHelper ch = ContentHelper.getContentHelper();

                                Person authenticatedPerson;
                                try
                                {
                                    authenticatedPerson = new Person(result.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(0));

                                    ch.insertAuthenticatedUser(authenticatedPerson);

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, ProfileEventActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);

                                    SignInActivity.this.finish();
                                }
                                catch (JSONException e)
                                {
                                    ToastHelper.make(R.string.toastNetworkError);
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                break;
                            default:
                                ToastHelper.make(R.string.toastNetworkError);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ToastHelper.make(R.string.toastNetworkError);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public DefAPI getAPI() {
                        return api;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Context getContext() {
                        return SignInActivity.this;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void bitmapDelegate(Bitmap bm, int position, int id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                }

                new SignInWithLinkedIn();

            }
        }

        new LinkedInToken(verifier).execute("");
    }

    class LinkedInLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
             oAuthService = LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory  
                        .getInstance()
                        .createLinkedInOAuthService(
                            "KEY","KEY2"
                        );

             factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory  
                            .newInstance("7obxzmefk9eu","rPsCyb8npka6jJHk");

             liToken = oAuthService.getOAuthRequestToken("x-oauthflow-linkedin://com.estudiotrilha.inevent");

             return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            intentToLinkedIn();
        }
    }

    public void startLinkedInLogin()
    {
        new LinkedInLogin().execute("");
    }

    public void intentToLinkedIn()
    {
        dialog.dismiss();
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                    Uri.parse(liToken.getAuthorizationUrl()));

        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: post the manifest file pls and the activity code.

Comment: and the activity code. `getActionbar()` returns null when there is no actionbar.

Comment: your mins sdk is 11. Why do you need AppCompat? Actionbar is available from api level 11. If you want below 11 then use AppCompat

Comment: What should I do? Just include the regular package, or I need code changes?

Comment: Just extend Activity. and there is no need for AppCompat. Use regular thems such as `Theme.Holo.Light` and customize

Answer (score 0):

Your activity should extend [ActionBarActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) and use [getSupportActionBar()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#getSupportActionBar%28%29) if your min SDK is 7-9.

If your min SDK is 10 or higher then extend Activity and use the regular HOLO themes.